# What is pseudocomplete data?

Tags: terminology, censoring, tobit-regression

Skimming [Huang *et al* 2019](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.8b07110) I see references to a term "pseudocomplete-data" that I am not familiar with. It looks like they are dealing with a data censoring problem which they approach with a [tobit regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tobit_model) but it is unclear what the precise meaning of this term is.

Here are the sentences that mention pseudocomplete-data.

> By combining computed values for censored observations estimated by the hurdle-gamma model and uncensored observations, we can get the pseudocomplete data sets.

> By doing so, one can also create a pseudocomplete-data set and thus, readily communicate spatial trends in the data set to decision makers and stakeholders.

What is pseudocomplete-data? Is there a precise definition? is it just another term for censored data? Or is it a new data set composed of the original data except that the missing entries have been filled with interpolated/estimated values?